# Making queries offline on local snapshot copy of Firestore Snapshot Query

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have following fields in a document at Firestore

```
Category: Online, OnSite, 
Status: true, false,
postTime: mm.dd.yyyy.hh.mm.ss
```

I am using following method to fetch the snapshot from Firebase with filter on Status & postTime.

```
 Future getData() async {
    QuerySnapshot qn = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection("items")
        .where("status", isEqualTo: true)
        .orderBy("postTime", descending: true)
        .get();

    return qn.docs;
  }
```

Now that I have `qn` with a copy of Firestore data, can I run more specific queries **OFFLINE** on `qn` where I can further filter it with `Category` ?

**Purpose** is: If the app user wants to further filter/sort some data then I do not want to consume data from Firestore for every query since the main data is already fetched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart has a convenient method called `where` for iterable objects that you can utilize to filter in various ways.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/where.html

Example:

```
final filteredDocs = qn.docs.where((doc) => doc.data()['status'] == 'pending').toList();
```

Comment: Worked after little tweak in my logic. Thanks a lot!